# Rewriting URL but keeping the active menu tab highlighted

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

A site I'm working on is set so that an active menu-tab is highlighted.

I needed to remove the menu tab name from the URL, so I redirected the URL to a form without the menu tab name like this (zaujalo-nas is the tab's alias)

```
RewriteRule ^zaujalo-nas/(.+)$ $1 [R=302,QSA,L]
```

However, after doing so, my level in URL was no longer this

```
domain.cz/menu-tab/article.html (which highlighted the menu tab I was at)
```

but this

```
domain.cz/article.html (which highlights the HOME menu-tab)
```

That is the problem (don't miss the brackets).

Both versions of URL work, however, the problem is highlighting the active menu-tab, which I want to keep as it was, not to change it to HOME - I'm not at the homepage actually.

It's a Joomla website, so I can't do anything like moving my .html file somewhere higher in the structure.

I tried to keep the URL redirected and display the original's URL content (which is the same), but I'm getting into a loop. Still, I'm not really sure if could help.

```
RewriteRule ^zaujalo-nas/(.+)$ $1 [R=302,QSA,L]    
RewriteRule ^([^.]+).html$ zaujalo-nas/$1.html [QSA,L]
```

I have to admit that I'm not using any RewriteConds, they weren't really needed so far.
Don't be scared of my R=302, I'm gonna keep it only till I have a stable htaccess which won't be changed anymore.

Is there a way to to go around this trouble?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is from within the Joomla Framework, and cannot be fixed using a redirect in the htaccess file.

You will need to setup a new menu item with the type Menu Item Alias. This new menu item can then be place in a new 'hidden' menu that will not be called anywhere. In that new menu item, set the alias to be the target menu item. Then, all you need to do is set the link for the new alias menu item to the shortened one you wish to have.

**EDIT**

You can also use SEO components to accomplish this task, if you need to redirect an entire category. A component like AceSEF should work, but there are many to choose from.

Comment: That seems to be kinda confusing and a bit unhandy solution, but I suppose it could be done as you say, it sounds reasonable. I'm using K2 for the whole site, so I'm not sure if it would be the same. About the SEO components, I would rather not use them as they can be very demanding and slowing the site down significantly. My solution is not removing the category in this case, I just removed the menu-tab names from links with "author" and "tag" to avoid duplication under different menu-tabs, that is enough for me as it does it's job perfectly. Never mind, thank you for your reply.

Comment: The idea is to use a menu item alias to display content under a different menu item with the desired URI path. Joomla has no way to know what content you are seeing without knowing either the component or menu item you are trying to load. So, you either need to set a redirect for every article, or you can't accomplish your goal.